# Why is all objective c source files recompiled when I modify any swift file in my project?

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm using Swift code in my iOS project which already had a lot of Objective C source files before I use Swift. Unfortunately, I suffer from long build time since I decided that.

I know that Swift 1.2 supports an incremental build feature, but I don't know why doesn't the feature work.

Is there any compile options for an incremental build in Xcode Setting to solve that problem? or should I wait for next version of Swift and Xcode?

In addition, I use Xcode 6.4 that supports Swift 1.2.

Comment: Because the bridging header changes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, recently, I was also facing the same problem so I have tweaked my Xcode settings and it's working quite good.

**What I have changed?**

> 1) Xcode Project > Build Settings > Build Active Architecture Only
>
> - For Debug: Yes
> - For Release: No
>
> 2) Stop generating dYSM file while debugging. To do so:
>
> - Xcode Project > Build Settings > Debug Information Format = DWARF
>
> 3) Stop Whole Module Optimization. To do so:
>
> - Xcode Project > Build Settings > Whole Module Optimization > NO

These settings will decrease compile time nearly about 20 - 25 seconds. Let me know, if you have any other techniques or issues

Comment: Sadly, the problem is not solved by your answer. I think I have to test with next Xcode and Swift version coming soon.